# Replace number with repeated characters

Tags: regex

Say I have a string: `8`, and I wanted to replace numbers `[0-9]` with a `.` that would repeat as many times as the number.  What regex string would I use?

e.g.: input string

```
8
```

output

```
........
```

Comment: In what language?

Comment: I don't know any regex flavor that is powerful enough for this in itself. However, most regex flavors allow you to specify a callback function for the replacement, where you could do all the magic.

Comment: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: No code, no research efforts, no elaboration, no language tag. Enough reasons to close this question.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this using only regular expressions so you'll have to rely on a language or library feature which allows substitution of matched strings with the result of calling a function with the match as an argument.

In Ruby:

```ruby
   "8".gsub(/[0-9]/) { |x| '.' * x.to_i } # => "........"
 "812".gsub(/[0-9]/) { |x| '.' * x.to_i } # => "..........."
"a1b2".gsub(/[0-9]/) { |x| '.' * x.to_i } # => "a.b.."
```

In JavaScript:

```javascript
function replaceNumbersWithDots(str) {
  return (''+str).replace(/[0-9]/g, function(m) {
    var s='', num=parseInt(m, 10);
    for (i=0; i<num; i++) { s+= '.'; }
    return s;
  });
}
replaceNumbersWithDots('8');    // => "........"
replaceNumbersWithDots('812');  // => ".........."
replaceNumbersWithDots('a1b2'); // => "a.b.."
```

In Java:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
  System.out.println(replaceNumbersWithDots("8"));    // => "........"
  System.out.println(replaceNumbersWithDots("812"));  // => "..........."
  System.out.println(replaceNumbersWithDots("a1b2")); // => "a.b.."
}
public static String replaceNumbersWithDots(String s) {
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
  StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
  while (matcher.find()) {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
    matcher.appendReplacement(buf, stringOfDots(x));
  }
  return buf.toString();
}
public static String stringOfDots(int x) {
  String s = "";
  for (int i=0; i<x; i++) { s += "."; }
  return s;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can't be done with standard regular expressions alone. As @m.buettner points out, you can in certain languages specify a function that processes the replacement. For example, with Python

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '8'
>>> re.sub(r'\d', lambda m: '.'*int(m.group()), s)
'........'
```

---

But maybe you don't even need a regex? Since you're only looking for single-character matches (namely `\d`), you can perhaps do something like this:

- Initialize some sort of string buffer to hold the resultant string
- Loop over the characters of your input string

  - If the character is a digit, parse it as an integer and append that many `.`s to your buffer.
  - Otherwise, append the character itself to your buffer.

Here's an implementation of this in Java:

```
String s = "8";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        int n = c - '0';

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            sb.append('.');
    } else {
        sb.append(c);
    }
}

System.out.println(sb);
```

```
........
```

Answer (score 2):

AS you didn't provide a lang, i made an exemple of solving it in php

```php
$tr = array();
foreach(range(0, 9) as $nr)
{
  $tr[$nr] = str_repeat('.', $nr);
}

echo strtr("Hello 8", $tr);
// Gives: "Hello ........"
```